# How to deal with incorrect claims in answers and comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

I have a situation I'm not quite sure how to deal with.

I am an open-source enthusiast and an author of several open-source libraries and tools. There are few tags on SO on my projects and I gladly consult users there - answer questions, offer advice etc.

I also have to say that some of my tools serve quite advanced use cases. So you actually have to know a great deal to be able to apply them. Normally everything works well because the users usually already have the required level.

Recently, however, I was trying to help a user who was trying to use one of my tools. No matter how hard I tried, I just didn't manage to help him out. He seemed to lack the understanding of the basic concepts of the tools he was trying to use, skipped important instructions, applied them incorrectly and tried completely wrong things - and ultimately blamed the tool for not doing what he wanted. It was a series of questions with lengthy discussions and comments-on-comments^20, I guess you understand what I mean.

Finally I've decided that I just don't have time for this; I've just terminated my efforts. The user eventually figured it out, BUT still blames the tool.

Finally what I have is a bunch of false claims of what my tool is capable of and what not. However you have to know the tool to see that these claims are false. And it's a very niche thing so not too many people with the relevant knowledge come around. An "average" (sorry for the word) reviewer wouldn't see that these comments are false.

Being false, these comments may be misleading for potential new users. They don't provide any constructive criticism whatsoever; it's more like "your tool is not mature enough to do X".

I don't know what to do about this. From one hand I don't really like these claims. From the other hand I don't want to engage the user anymore. I would appreciate the community advice here. Right now I'm just backing off.

Comment: `Right now I'm just backing off.` Good first step.

Comment: You can't do anything about it. There's an incorrect comment with 350 upvotes on one of my answers. But hey, it's another case of
: http://xkcd.com/386/

Comment: Also remember that comments are second hand citizens, they should not contain important information. If they do, move them into the post. If the _post_ contains bad information, edit, downvote, and comment.

Comment: Just leave a comment explaining your point of view and downvote if appropriate. Then forget about it. You will never convince the OP, but future generations will see your comment and can make up their own mind.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I've tried this one or two times, this just starts a new "but how does it work then?" thread.

Comment: @lexicore Then that person is probably a help vampire and if you're bothered by it, just move on to a different question.

Comment: @gunr2171: In one of the cases I took 2 hours and wrote a real step-by-step tutorial which explain the solution in detail. Checked and rechecked. The user didn't get it, commented like "does not work". And finally posted his own 5-line answer to his own question containing a false claim. So it's not just comments.

Comment: @Mysticial Probably the right thing to do. May hurt the reputation of the tool.

Comment: Q.: "**What are step by step instructions** ..?" [sic, including **bold**] You: "Ok, this is gonna be lengthy ..." I say, close as "too broad" as it's out of SO's remit to provide baby steps. At least you gave it a valiant and honest attempt.

Comment: @Jongware I actually did not want to drag the discussion here ("Look! Look! tell me I was right!"). Very good idea with "too broad".

Comment: @lexicore: If your tool requires that level of expertise, then the experts will know how to spot a incompetent user too.

Comment: FWIW I got the question you are referring to in my Low Quality Posts queue. It was clear that the user was part of the problem and did not fully understand the tool. I ended up hitting "skip" because I did not have the background to assess the situation, but I don't think anyone will look at that as a definitive word about the tool.

Comment: @Mysticial: We-who-are-wrong-on-the-Internet have consulted amongst ourselves, and decided that 350 votes on an incorrect comment is a travesty.  But have no fear, this sad situation can be remedied.  Please link this comment so that we may raise the vote count to truly stratospheric levels.

Comment: @BenVoigt lol. I don't have too many answers that get 100-upvote comments. (let alone 350) You don't have to search very hard. :D

Comment: *"Recently, however, I was trying to help a user which was trying to use one of my tools"* - since its a tool, I would expect this conversation to occur on another site in the Stack Exchange network. (Unless you write compilers, linkers, repo browsers, etc). Can you provide a link to a conversation?

Comment: @jww This one is a code generation tool. Please send me a mail, I'll provide a link. I think it is not fair to link to those discussions there. See my profile, my contact data is there.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I've seen both situations:

1. The user blames the tool when the user is the problem.
2. The tool's author insists that the tool is working correctly or is well designed, when it is in fact not working correctly or is badly designed.

Who is correct is a technical matter, and so long as the matter remains technical and there is no violation of the site rules, moderators are not going to step into the dispute.

So what is one to do? The best advice is to explain why the person is wrong, downvote where possible and desirable, and move on.

Comment: Ah the wonders of [PEBCAK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error)

Comment: Yes, I also understand how it may look like for the not involved observer. I would have really loved to learn what I could improve, but found out that it works the way it should OOTB (was surprised by that, actually).
Ok, so, the last engagement and move on. Can I "close" the question somehow to protect it from further false claims? Probably not. But OK.

Comment: @lexicore There has to be a legitimate close reason to close a question. "False claims" by themselves are not a good reason.

Comment: @lexicore, if the conversation gets _too_ out of hand you can flag for moderator attention, either to clean up the comments or lock the post.

Comment: @Louis Yes, I understand that. Just don't want to waste time on further claims.

Comment: @gunr2171 The solution is obviously to post lots of unconstructive comments so that a moderator removes all of them.

Comment: @gunr2171 No, no, it was not that bad.

Comment: @lexicore Let me add this. It has happened that when I posted an answer, I got an additional question from the OP in a comment on my answer and then we've had a discussion in comments until at some point I realized that what I thought was a *clear* question was in fact not clear at all, and thus was worthy of being closed for being unclear. So there is this avenue, but other folks will have to see it the way you do for the question to be finally closed.

Comment: @gunr2171: Upvoted your comment for the irony.

Answer (score 12):

I am answering my own question here as I believe I have learned quite a few things. From the answers and comments here as well as from the whole situation.

- I should not hesitate to close "how to make this work" type of questions as "too broad". Even if I am willing to help and even if I think I know the answer for the whole thing. This is important for the following reasons:

  - The OP gets correcting feedback that his question is not good enough.
  - I am probably the only one who is able to answer "the whole thing". Dividing the question into a series of simpler ones will increase the probablity that other people would be able to help as well. Basically, all the parts of the original question are quite common and mainstream and known to many people. It's the combination that makes the target audience quite small.
  - Closing is not my personal decision, it takes up to five people to close one. It makes it pretty much unlikely that closing will be interpreted as a personal "insult" or "denial of service".
  - One big question benefits one user, many small questions benefit the community.
- I should not engage in lengthy (constructive or not) discussions in comments and answers. Mark question-comments as "this is another question" an move on. This may result in further questions which is altogether more productive.
- I should stay constructive, never get personal, whatever it takes. I do not have a goal to "teach" this specific user how to think/work/research/experiment etc. I was not asked to. :)
- I should not worry much about "false claims". Most people will recognize the real nature of things and also my effort to help. Those who will not are, probably, in the same category as this user and it does not worth to try to change their mind anyway.
- When in doubt, stay calm and move on.

---

Now for those interested, this story had a continuation.

After I have decided to leave my user alone, I really saw im struggling. He asked a number of further questions (which were getting narrower and narrower) and managed a few steps, but unfortunatelly nor in the right direction. It looked like he really put significant effort in making it work.

Finally, I just could not resist it. I took time and addressed his most critical question. This was, again, a lengthy post with screenshots, code examples, links to working samples etc. AND also built-in "quality gates" like "don't move on until THIS works".

I admit, I did not have high hopes, **but it worked**. I believe the user carried out the steps with greater care and it looks like it finally worked for him! He managed to run basic examples, tried few things on his own (met new problems on that way), but he clearly has this "Hello, World!" past him.

He asked new questions but at least one of them is now closed as "too broad". And having learned the things I learned, I am trying to restructure the incoming questions and comments so that we get small easy-to handle questions where I am not the only source of wisdom (or lack thereof).

Nor sure if this is appropriate here, but I would like to thank you, the people, who help me to learn how to handle this situation. I will benefit from this lesson in the future.

---

**UPDATE**

Right after I've written this "happy end" post, the user has found out that his "too broad" question was closed. He now:

- accused me of being short-tempered
- claimed that he has provided "invaluable feedback" for me to fix things and I was not grateful for that
- removed his aggressive comments later on
- added an update to his post, with an explicit purpose to defame the project as "not having an adequate documentation"
- and was still asking me to help to resolve things.

So, sorry, this is not a happy end. This is a big disappointment and a good lesson for me.

Now I will have to do two things:

- Add another lesson to the list above: **If my gut feeling says that I'm probably trying to help the wrong person, I better listen to it.**
- Practice what I've learned. Stay constructive. Disengage. Flag if appropriate. Forget and move on.

Sincerely yours,

Comment: "Nor sure if this is appropriate here" It is 100% appropriate. Your bullet points provide excellent guidance to anyone in a similar situation. Things will not always work out as well as they apparently have in this user's case, but the chances are improved by following the suggestions you've outlined.

Comment: Approach it this way: through his actions and claims, this one user has lost the prerogative of your free help. And all days will be sunny.

Comment: @Jongware Honestly, I was laughing to myself: no I have an opportunity to practice what I learned.

Answer (score 4):

As someone who hasn't been in the same situation as you, but has read plenty of painfully incorrect claims on the internet - don't stress about it too much, because any reasonably interested reader can usually tell who's acting willfully ignorant and who's making sense in an internet discussion. All you can/should reasonably do in this situation is calmly reassert the truth of the matter and trust that clear heads will prevail. There's no good to come with debating/arguing with someone who's clearly not interested in genuine help.

Comment: +1. They might not be interested in help or they might be too stressed/unconfident to realize the type of help they need.

Comment: Or felt too embarrassed to admit their earlier claims are false.