# how does SO manage deliberately wrong answers and comments?

Tags: discussion

a deliberately wrong answer or comment is not necessarily easy to spot.

a friend of mine is just starting Android development and has searched SO for answers to a specific issue.  My friend suspects there are persons who create wrong answers to misguide others; while this seems far fetched, my friend thinks that SO comments are mostly by such persons (imho this is highly unlikely).

a new SO member like my friend would not have enough reputation points to delete a wrong answer; is there a mechanism in SO to "alert moderators" such as is found in forums.asp.net?

This answer to my meta question is somewhat close, but seems to say just ignore it which is contrary to the SO attempt to strive for quality Q&A:  [How to deal with incorrect claims in answers and comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274396/how-to-deal-with-incorrect-claims-in-answers-and-comments)

a search of meta SO for "alert moderators" did not help.

if there is currently no SO mechanism to alert moderators, perhaps some symbol below the star for favourites could be used for that purpose.

Comment: _"if there is currently no SO mechanism to alert moderators, ..."_ There is?!? Flagging questions, answers or comments is purposed for doing so.

Comment: sorry.  my bad.  missed "flag" below tags.  my blind. mea culpa

Comment: "my friend thinks that SO comments are mostly by such persons"  Your friend is delusional.  Showing him how to flag will be a major annoyance (and disservice) to the moderators, and probably get him flag-banned, if not worse.

Comment: Does, by any chance, your friend also believe that the Apollo missions were faked and that Area 51 is a prison for captured aliens?

Comment: @Martin, there's no point having a prison for _dead_ aliens, it's more of a morgue and lab for testing the captured spacecraft :-)

Comment: comments about the area whose number can not be spoken are highly likely to have conspiracy theorists directed by the über intelligence a.k.a. Google driven here in search for the meaning of life.  B-) ... FWIW, my friend is not crazy, just frustrated with getting his first Android development environment off the ground.  Pekka has answered my question.  Thanks to all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, the right tool to combat incorrect answers is downvoting and commenting.

If you really suspect users deliberately posting incorrect and harmful answers on a large scale, alert moderators through a custom flag, or E-Mail `team@stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: thnx ... what is a **custom** flag?

Comment: Sorry, it's not actually labeled that way. I mean the one that says `Other (needs ♦ moderator attention)` where you can enter a custom message.